# Best method for handling the display of a lot of text

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a screen where I am going to display a lot of text. I have the text saved in an array of strings. 15 Headings and 15 body texts.

I was wondering what is the best method of handing this? Convert it to HTML and use a webview or maybe some kind of textview ?

I was thinking a table could work too possibly, though I am probably making it more complicated than it needs to be. The text is read only there will be no editing. Just to buttons at the bottom of the screen to exit.

I've never done anything like this on the iphone so I would like advice and tips please.

Thanks
-Code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UITextView if there's no styling or UIWebView if you have styles on your text.

Or you can can for pages if you want that kind of navigation and not a simple scroll.

Comment: I will need to make bold the headers. And have some spacing etc.